# FastZip.ExtractZip does not extract subfolder but name gets corrupted

Tags: c#, mono, sharpziplib

On mono 2.0.1 (and other version) when I extact a zip file with subfolders it wrongly creates the new files on local filesystem.

```
FastZip fs = new FastZip();
fs.ExtractZip(LocalFile, LocalFolder, "");
```

will results in files created in this form (all files, no subfolders, that backslash "\" is IN the filename!)

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 brainstorm brainstorm 74459 2009-03-12 23:20 images\bg.jpg 
-rw-r--r-- 1 brainstorm brainstorm 76188 2009-03-12 23:20 images\creditsbg.jpg 
-rw-r--r-- 1 brainstorm brainstorm 496 2009-03-12 23:20 images\credits.html 
-rw-r--r-- 1 brainstorm brainstorm 427571 2009-03-12 23:20 images\creditsleft.jpg
```

Please note: these are files not files in folder images. 
This behavior is ofcourse wrong, it should create a folder called "images" and store the bg.jpg etc in that newly created folder.

Anyone here able to help me?

Comment: I guess you should contact FastZip developers, or how it is used in OpenSource world, 'submit a patch'.

Comment: Question is an exact copy of the SharpZipLib forums, dated 2009-03-13. (Four years ago!?). http://community.sharpdevelop.net/forums/p/9187/25577.aspx